# wifi p2p network with channels

Tags: java, android, sockets, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I read about [P2P connections with wifi](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html) on the official android tutorial. It allows me to connect devices who are in close proximity. The problem is that

1. I want to be able to decide which device becomes the *group owner*
2. I don't want to use the device name as an ID for each peer in the network. I would like the group owner to setup a *channel name* which can be recognized by others. Each peer can connect to the channel name and choose a name (not their device name).

Maybe the standard direct wifi implementation as put forth in the tutorial isn't the exact tool I'm looking for. Maybe a third party library could help?

Comment: For the first solution you can set the value of `groupOwnerIntent` between 0 to 15 in which 15 being the highest value to be the group owner by using `WifiP2pConfig config`

Answer (score 0):

Basically the API has the functionality to do just this (though the implementation is not the most robust one, so do expect issues when developing & using the API):

1. Use the CreateGroup to create the group
2. Start local service advertisement with the group owner (set the Service type and/or the instance name to identify the 'channel name')
3. Start and Do remember to keep peers discovery active with your GO (otherwise other devices can not discover it)
4. Start Peer discovery with other devices, and once you find peers, then start Service discovery and discover the 'channel name' services yor GO is advertising